# Noether's theorem and Invariance of Lagrangian under translation

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, reference-frames, conservation-laws, symmetry, noethers-theorem

Consider a coordinate system in which the point A has coordinate $z_0$ and point B has ccordinate $z$ where there is a particle of mass $m$. Let there be a constant gravitational field of Earth. The Lagrangian of a particle in this system is given by $$L=\frac{1}{2}m(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2+\dot{z}^2)-mg(z-z_0)$$ where the potential energy of point B is measured w.r.t point A. Now consider different coordinate system where the origin is shifted from $x=y=z=0$ to $x=y=0,z=\alpha$. In this coordinate, A has coordinate $z_0+\alpha$ and B has coordinate $z+\alpha$. Therefore, *although the coordinate $z$ is not cyclic*, the Lagrangian remains invariant under translation in the $z$ direction. Therefore, by Noether's theorem, the momentum $p_z$ should be conserved. But as we know this is not the case due to constant gravitational field along $z$-direction. Is this not a contradiction?

Comment: If your $z_0$ is a *fixed point*, then it is *not acted upon by translation*. By definition, a symmetry transformation can only act on the dynamical variables, not on constants, so your Lagrangian is not invariant.

Comment: A is a fixed point. $z_0$ is the coordinate label of A that will change under the change of coordinates system. I don't get your point. Think of a coordinate system and translating it.

Comment: Here I'm talking about translating the coordinate system not the particle itself. If I changed the location of the particle B, then yes, you're right.

Comment: You have to look at what a transformation for the Noether theorem is - it is a transformation *of the dynamical variables*. Your translation of the coordinate system does not fulfill the technical prerequisites of Noether's theorem.

Comment: Okay. Now this makes sense to me. It is true that if a coordinate is cyclic, the corresponding linear momentum is conserved (as can be seen from Euler-Lagrange equation). Is the reverse also true? I mean, can the Lagrangian be invariant under $q_i\rightarrow q_i+\alpha$ without $q_i's$ being cyclic? Or should I post it as a different question?

Comment: @SRS That is simply the meaning of "cyclic".

Comment: I was thinking of a different mathematical scenario (and looking for a physical realization) in which the Lagrangian is conserved under translation without the coordinated being cyclic. For example, can we not have two different dynamical variables $x$ and $y$, appearing in the potential as some function of $f(x-y)$? If this be the case, neither $x$, nor $y$ will be cyclic. However, the Lagrangian $L$ will be invariant under $x\rightarrow x+\alpha$ and $y\rightarrow y+\alpha$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. ACuriousMind has already pointed out in comments the crucial point: $z_0$ is an external parameter, not an dynamical variable of the action $S[x,y,z]$.
2. OP then ponders in a comment what happens if we artificially promote $z_0$ to a dynamical variable of the action $S[x,y,z,z_0]$? Nevermind this possibly does not make physical sense. What would be the mathematical consequences for [Noether's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether's_theorem)?
3. OK, let's investigate. The translations $$ z ~\longrightarrow ~ z+\alpha, \qquad z_0 ~\longrightarrow ~ z_0+\alpha $$ is indeed an exact off-shell symmetry of the action $S[x,y,z,z_0]$. Noether's theorem then therefore states that the corresponding Noether charge $$p_z~:=~\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{z}}$$
   is conserved on-shell
   $$ \frac{dp_z}{dt}~\approx~0. $$
   [Here the $\approx$ symbol means equality modulo eom.]
4. Only trouble is that the eom for $z_0$ reads
   $$ 0~\approx~\frac{\delta S}{\delta z_0}~=~mg, $$
   i.e. if we want to put the system on-shell, we would have to turn off gravity! And then $p_z$ would be conserved on-shell. Therefore Noether's theorem is not violated.